# Ruby REDIS with EX AND NX

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, locking

I am trying to implement a locking in our rails application server.

REDIS.setnx works fine if I want to acquire a lock forever. But I want to acquire lock with expiry, basically I want the lock to expire after certain duration so that lock will be free to be acquired again.

From REDIS's set documentation, I see it is possible. https://redis.io/commands/set
"The command SET resource-name anystring NX EX max-lock-time is a simple way to implement a locking system with Redis."

How to implement this in ruby.
Command :

```
REDIS = Redis.new(host: ENV['REDIS_HOST'], port: ENV['REDIS_PORT'])
REDIS.set "key", "value", "nx", "ex", 3600
```

throws error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 2..3)
```

There is another way to do that, but it requires two REDIS calls.

```
if(REDIS.setnx "key", "value")
    REDIS.setex "key", 3600, "value"
end
```

This method is not preferred. I am looking to a way to acquire REDIS lock with single REDIS call in ruby. Basically "SET resource-name anystring NX EX max-lock-time" equivalent in ruby.

Thanks,

Anshul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this was added in Redis(the gem) in v3.2.2, [see PR 547](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/pull/547).
It should be used like a flag rather than as a bare string, [see test](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/60971a1723c70609974535a3cdbbcf92ae136629/test/lint/strings.rb#L52).

```
r.set("foo", "qux", :nx => true)
```

Which leads me to believe you should be able to do this:

```
r.set("foo", "qux", :nx => true, :ex => 2.hours)
```

Comment: Looks like there is a minor difference from what you have commented.

Comment: REDIS.set("foo2", "qux", :nx => true, :ex => 2.hours) works. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Interesting that they don't use the expires_in or expires_at flag same as with normal keys. I opened an issue to ask if there's value around using expires_in as well as EX: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/738